# Using Paperclip with Non-US S3 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

i am having some problem integrating Paperclip with non-us S3 server. Paperclip seem to assume that the S3 server is in us and return back a url that is at http://s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/my/file.

My question is how to change it to point to a non-us S3 server(singapore for example)? The files are uploading, i just need to get paperclip to return a correct path.

Using :

- paperclip-2.4.5
- aws-s3-0.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Tian Wei, check this out:

http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/amazons-s3-european-buckets-and-paperclip-in-rails-3/

But a better answer would be just use the US one, and avoid the hassle.

Comment: Tried that guide already but it did not work for me. I am current using the US one but latency seem to be an issue.

Comment: Unless you need to full sized pictures, its always a better idea to use paperclips methods to scale them down.